# Speakers don't mute when headphones are plugged in

Tags: windows

I am using windows 8 version 6.6.9200 build 9200 in HP pavilion sleekbook 14 and whenever i plug in headphones both speakers and headphones continue working simultaneously

Comment: As a test, start some audio and try pushing the headphone plug farther in and wiggle it.  Listen for whether you hear any interruption on the speakers.  If you have any other headphones or external speakers, try plugging them in.  This is to test whether the problem might be with the internal switch in the jack that is supposed to open when you plug something in.  Also, it's a combo jack.  Are you using just headphones or combo headphones with mic?  It shouldn't make a difference but the plug is slightly different so just covering the bases.

Comment: I did a quick search to see if others have reported the same issue.  See: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-PC-Sound-and-Audio/HP-Pavilion-Sleekbook-14-speakers-keep-playing-while/td-p/2713927 from the HP support forum.  Not only did the suggested fix not help, a replacement machine had the same problem.  At least yours is "working" though.  Many other posts report no sound at all (or other, related problems).